# Control Windows with remote keyboard+mouse and local display?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a dedicated display plugged into my Windows machine, but would like to control it with a remote keyboard [edit: specifically, the keyboard on my laptop].  Is there a way to control the Windows machine with a remote keyboard while using the local display?

(I've used Microsoft Remote Desktop for remote keyboard / remote display and it works well, but I haven't found a way to configure it for remote keyboard / local display.)

Comment: any wireless keyboard… unless I'm missing something, like you mean from the next county...

Comment: I should have been more specific: the keyboard in question is firmly attached to my laptop.  I've edited the OP accordingly.

Comment: As I think about it, I'd be surprised if there's a way to do what I want: how would my laptop know when I've activated the Windows display?

Comment: I'm now lost as to what you're actually trying to do. Where is this mysterious display in relation to your laptop? If it's connected directly to the laptop simply as an extended display, then it's controlled in exactly the same way as your built-in display is controlled… by any keyboard/mouse/trackpad connected to the laptop; built-in, or via USB, Bluetooth etc.

Comment: The display is directly connected to my Intel NUC running Windows10.  No keyboard.  I'd like to use my laptop's kbd/mouse to control it.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered several times here on Superuser, as well as elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: @music2myear: Thanks for the pointer to Synergy.  Accepting this question as a duplicate.